# Weathericons.io integration with APIs

Tags: icons, openweathermap

I'm trying to get Weather Icons to display based on the ID number given to me from the Open Weather Maps API. From readin weathericons.io's page on API integration here[1](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/api-list.html), I'm lead to believe that if I put

```
<i class="wi wi-owm-800"></i>
```

into my HTML, I'd get the icon for sunny day - but nothing shows. If I write it as

```
<i class="wi wi-day-sunny></i>
```

then I get the correct icon.

Is there any way to do this using the ID number given to me by OWM?